Destruction of Books in Jihad
A quote attributed to Kitab al-Wagiz fi fiqh madhab al-imam al-Safi'i states that during Jihad:

One must destroy their useless books.

However, when I searched online, most results were from anti-Islamic blogs and forums that merely repeat the quote without offering any context. I would like to read the original quote in its full context. Additionally, I want to understand its proper meaning as understood by devout Muslims. Does it mean that all books are to be destroyed, or is there a specific criterion that makes a book "useless"?

Could you please provide the Arabic source of the text?

The relevant text is:

ويجب إهلاك كتبهم التي لا يحل الانتفاع بها
It is obligatory to destroy their books, those from which it is not permissible to take benefit
— Al-Wajiz fi Fiqh al-Imam al-Shafi'i

The context is that this is talking about what can be done with the property of the disbelievers when the Muslims gain control over it during war. In this case it is about the books obtained from the disbelievers.
If a book is such that it is permissible for a Muslim to take benefit from it, then it is to be distributed among the soldiers like other spoils of war. The soldiers can legally own such books and can do whatever they like such as studying them or selling them etc. This includes books on medicine, poetry, mathematics, language, history etc.
If the book is such that it is not permissible for a Muslim to benefit from it, then it is to be destroyed. A Muslim can not benefit from it himself, and he also can not sell it or give it to another person as that is assisting in sin - rather he must dispose of it. Such books include those propagating kufr\shirk, philosophy, mockery, obscenity, witchcraft, astrology etc. Destroying a book can be done by burning it or by putting it into a river or by burying it underground etc. If it is possible to erase the text and reuse the paper and binding then that is permissible. There is disagreement on whether it is permitted to keep books on the religious beliefs of the disbelievers in order to obtain information about their viewpoints so that they can be refuted.
Ref: al-‘Aziz bi Sharh al-Wajiz and  Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah
